# The postfix in inter.broker.protocol.version of Apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

When rolling upgrade Kafka brokers, I found a mismatch between the official doc says.

The default is `inter.broker.protocol.version=2.3-IV1`,

and https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_3_0 says setting `inter.broker.protocol.version=2.3`

Is there any difference between using `2.3-IV1` and `2.3`?

Answer (score 1):

by looking at the code, 2.3 would be 2.3-IV0 (see https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/api/ApiVersion.scala#L305) and the difference between 2.3-IV0 and IV1 would be `Add rack_id to FetchRequest, preferred_read_replica to FetchResponse, and replica_id to OffsetsForLeaderRequest` - according to [this comment](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/api/ApiVersion.scala#L92)

Comment: hmm, I'm not very sure why  2.3-IV1 is not picked up because both are case classes without a default setup?